# How is a highway prevented from being buried by sand in the desert?

Tags: civil-engineering

When I happened to see pictures of a highway in the desert, the question arose in my mind. The highway will probably be buried if a sandstorm rages. So is there any solution to this problem?
https://www.sciencenews.org/blog/wild-things/algal-blooms-created-ancient-whale-graveyard

[image]

Comment: They keep clearing it. But nature is likely to win.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual solution is to build a fence with lots of slats in it about 20 feet away from the edge of the road. The fence slows down the airflow and thereby causes the sand in it to fall out and accumulate right behind the fence, thereby keeping most of it off the road.

Since most of the sand carried by the wind scoots along close the surface of the ground, the fence does not have to be more than 4 or 5 feet tall to catch most of the sand.

Once the fence is about half-buried in sand, its effectiveness diminishes and the sand around it has to be plowed away.

Comment: Why is this solution not widely adopted now?

Comment: It is, for dune stabilization in europe. Planting grasses does the trick too and this makes the "fence" self-propagating.

Comment: Almost sounds exactly like snow fencing used in Canada.  helps deal with drifting snow on the road.

Comment: Grass can hardly survive in the desert unless it's a drought tolerant variety.